# i want to run a python script from another python script passing in arguments and a function in between

Tags: python, pyqt

So basically what i want to do is to run a python script called "p1.py" from another python script, knowing that when i usually run the p1.py in my terminal i run it this way :

```
./directory/p1.py train /path/to/dataset/
```

I used : `subprocess.call(['f1.py','/path/to/dataset/'])` 
but this only works with command line arguments and doesn't accept function in between them . 
How can i possibly fix this problem knowing that i already searched for similar problems but i didn't find anything related to my case .

Comment: from <script_name> import <function_name>

Comment: i did that but i don't know how to use the function like i did in the command line

Comment: @deepmore then read the doc (and/or the source code) to learn how it works.

Answer (score 0):

use python's built in execfile method https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile

`execfile('./directory/p1.py')`

Comment: execfile function only takes a file and 2 additional dictionaries as arguments from what i understood from documentation what i want is smt like this : execfile('./directory/p1.py',train,'/my/path/') which doesnt work because train is a function and not a dictionary